# JSON carrega em localhost mas não em produção

Tags: json

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto de site que usa arquivos JSON para alimentar os dados dinâmicos. No localhost, usando o XAMPP, os dados são carregados mas quando subo para um servidor de produção a página não lê os arquivos JSON, retorna NULL onde deveriam aparecer os dados. Todo o projeto, arquivos html, js, css, Json, imagens, etc, estão no mesmo domínio. Há alguma forma de configuração no servidor que possa está causando isso? Sei que há limitação se o arquivo JSON estiver num domínio diferente (cross domain). Não é o caso.

O HTML está assim:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="slides" id="carregaSlides">
    </div>
</div>
```

No JS está assim:

```
function carregaSlides() {
    loadSlide ="";
    //$("#carregaSlides").html("");
    $.getJSON('json/slides.json', function(data){

        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            loadSlide += "<div class='slider'><div class='legend'></div><div class='content'><div class='content-txt'></div></div><div class='image'><img src='slides/"+ val.slide +"' class='imgSlide'></div></div>";
            $("#carregaSlides").html(loadSlide);
        });

});

}
```

Comment: Já conferiu permissões de leitura dos arquivos?

Comment: Tens de dar mais informações para podermos ajudar... a linguagem do servidor, o código que carrega o ficheiro, etc...

Comment: Já. A pasta onde estão os arquivos json está com permissão de leitura e gravação, já que eles serão atualizados automaticamente por outra aplicação em PHP

Comment: @Sergio, é uma aplicação simples em HTML, uma página apenas. Localmente funciona bem. Alimenta uma div com dados do JSON. Quando coloco em produção não acontece. É como se não tivesse permissão para ler o arquivo, como citou Hamurabi. Não é o caso. Já verifiquei permissões na pasta.

Comment: Qual/como é a linha de código que carrega esse ficheiro?

Comment: O que dá `console.log(typeof data, data);`?

Comment: @Sergio TypeError: previouslyActive.classList is undefined[Learn More]

Comment: @RonaldoDantas, uma pergunta meio idiota, mas só pra ter certeza mesmo: ele tá encontrando o arquivo ou está dando 404? Só pra saber se não está dando problemas com os links relativos.

Comment: tente usar o link completo e não o relativo na URL.

Comment: Testa o link do teu site URL/json/slides.json. Isso funciona?

Comment: Amigos, resolvi! Falei com um dos admins da rede aqui na repartição e ele me passou que é uma restrição de segurança. Sugeriu que ao invés de usar arquivo .json usasse um arquivo .php que retorna dados com a estrutura de um arquivo json, como preciso. Funcionou. Agradeço a ajuda de todos.
Lá no código troquei $.getJSON('json/slides.json', function(data) por $.getJSON('json/slides.php', function(data)